# Go: Am I creating too many values?

Tags: go

If I have a struct like this

```
type myStruct struct {
    mystring string
    myint int
}
```

and if I have a function that returns a new myStruct like this

```
func New() myStruct {
    s := myStruct{}

    s.mystring = "string"
    s.myint = 1

    return s
}
```

Because I first store it in the "s" variable before returning it, is my function actually making 2 myStruct values instead of one?

And if so, is it then a better practice to make sure I don't first store it in the variable?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I remember there was a syntax like `func New() (s myStruct){ ... }` which would do the allocation of the result for you. That might be faster. Do you use google go or gccgo?

Comment: I am using the Google go command. I would be curious if that syntax would have the same effect, or if it avoids the problem somehow.

Comment: see the accepted answer... defining it as `func New() (s myStruct)` will let the compiler allocate the struct for you before entering your function body. it should work out the same way as the answer from jdi. still you can't be sure, cause the specs/implementations of go are changing permanently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `return` statement will return a copy of the `myStruct` object value. If it is a small object then this is fine.

If you intend for the caller to be able to modify this object, and the struct will have methods that use a pointer as the receiver, then it makes more sense to return a pointer to your struct instead:

```
func New() *myStruct {
    s := myStruct{}

    s.mystring = "string"
    s.myint = 1

    return &s
}
```

You can see the copy happening when you compare the memory address of value vs pointer return types:  http://play.golang.org/p/sj6mivYSHg

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myStruct struct {
    mystring string
    myint    int
}

func NewObj() myStruct {
    s := myStruct{}
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &s)

    return s
}

func NewPtr() *myStruct {
    s := &myStruct{}
    fmt.Printf("%p\n",s)
    return s
}

func main() {

    o := NewObj()
    fmt.Printf("%p\n",&o)

    p := NewPtr()
    fmt.Printf("%p\n",p)
}


0xf8400235a0 // obj inside NewObj()
0xf840023580 // obj returned to caller
0xf840023640 // ptr inside of NewPtr()
0xf840023640 // ptr returned to caller
```

Comment: Thanks, in this particular case I do want to return a myStruct value instead of a pointer, but it seems that you're right that it returns a copy, unless I declare the `s` in the function signature, which seems to give different behavior.

Comment: Ah yes, looking at the memory address completely clears it up for me. Thanks much!

Comment: Ha, learned a lot from your Python answers, now learning from your Go answers - I'd +1 again if I could.

Comment: Do you really need reflect? `fmt.Printf("%p")` seems to do the trick for me. Any drawbacks? Code: http://play.golang.org/p/sj6mivYSHg

Comment: @topskip: No you are right. I was just using it kind of willy nilly to get to the same result. I will update to your example to make it more concise.

Answer (score 3):

I'm definitely not a Go expert (or even novice :) ), but as @max.haredoom mentioned, you can allocate variables in the function signature itself. In that way, you can also omit the `s` in the `return`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myStruct struct {
    mystring string
    myint    int
}

func New() (s myStruct) {
    s.mystring = "string"
    s.myint = 1

    return
}

func main() {
    r := New()
    fmt.Println(r)
}

// Outputs {string 1}
```

In the examples that I have come across in [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html), it does seem to be the most common way of doing things of this nature, but again, I am definitely not an authority on the subject (and will look for additional info on the actual performance).

Comment: Thanks. I think I found that my original version was making a copy, but doing the same test using your version, it seems that the copy is avoided. Here's the test I used, but updated with your solution. http://play.golang.org/p/66mqsVFbs_

Comment: Just don't go too crazy with the implicit returns, in most cases they tend to be bad practice

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer by using defer.

I updated the function so that there's a deferred modification to the myStruct value. This means it will happen after the return, but before it is received on the other end.

When I do this, the struct that is received by the caller does not show the updated value, so it appears as though I am indeed returning a copy.

```
func New() myStruct {
    s := myStruct{}

    defer func() {
        s.mystring = "new value" // defer an update to the value
    }()

    s.mystring = "string"
    s.myint = 1

    return s
}

func main() {

    b := New()

    fmt.Println(b) // still shows the original value
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/WWQi8HpDny